# How to add a range filter/query to a Dojo ItemFileReadStore

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

"Suppose you have a JSON which is the source for a Dojo ItemFileReadStore, that store underlies a Dojo DataGrid, named bdayGrid, and it has two attributes per row, "name" and "birthday".  Let's say the birthdays are stored in yyyy-mm-dd format (i.e. 1998-03-14):

```
{
  "items": [
    { "name": "Bob", "birthdate": { "_type": "Date", "_value": "1965-08-20"},
    { "name": "Jack", "birthdate": { "_type": "Date", "_value": "1969-11-12"},
    { "name": "Will", "birthdate": { "_type": "Date", "_value": "1998-04-20"}
  ]
}
```

Assume also you have two valid dates stored that define a date range:

```
var beginDate = "1995-01-05";
var endDate = "2016-01-01";
```

Then how can you code a query on the ItemFileReadStore that will effectively filter by that date range?  It seems easy to filter by a single value; you code something like:

```
 bdayGrid.filter({birthday: "1965-08-20"});
```

But how to pass in a high/low value pair to be used to filter a date within a range? Do you have to code a custom Dojo DataStore **QueryEngine**?  If so, how would that look?

Answer (score 0):

I think the filter mechanism is not appropriate for this application.

I would add another boolean field (e.g. `_show`) to the data and filter for that field. I would then loop though the store items, check if they match my date range and set the boolean field accordingly.

I think you will need to use an ItemFileWriteStore in order to change this field.

It would probably also be easier to use the `Date` for the dates.

```
function filter(/*Date*/ startDate, /*Date*/ endDate){
  store.fetch({
    onItem: function(item){
      var date = store.getValue(item, '_value');
      store.setValue(item, '_show', (startDate <= date) && (date <= endDate));
    }))
  });
}
```